# Is mixing a class and a function based views in Djago an acceptable practice?

Tags: python, django, django-views

My project is using class based views, but I can't build a custom 500 error page using this approach.

Using class based view:

`client_interface/views/errors/server_error_view.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View


class ServerErrorView(View):
    def get(request):
        return render(request, "client_interface/errors/500.html")
```

`urls.py`:

```
from client_interface.views.errors.server_error_view import ServerErrorView
handler500 = ServerErrorView.as_view()
```

It always returns `?: (urls.E007) The custom handler500 view 'client_interface.views.errors.server_error_view.ServerErrorView' does not take the correct number of arguments (request).` I've tried to change arguments of the `get` method to `(self, request)`, or `(*args)`, but the error remains the same.

From the other hand if I use function based view:

`client_interface/views/errors/server_error_view`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def custom_error_view(request):
    return render(request, "client_interface/errors/500.html", {})
```

`urls.py`

```
handler500 = 'client_interface.views.errors.server_error_view.custom_error_view'
```

Everything works fine.

So now, I'm  wondering if it's acceptable to have one function based view, and the rest of the application will be class based, or is it a crime in django world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a [built-in 500 error view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view)

You can create a `500.html` template in your root template directory if you need. Basically you don't have to create a view for that.

Answering your question: if you know what you're doing having class based views and function based ones is ok. Just be clear on your ideas so that other devs or yourself later could grasp that idea and maintain your code with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get` class method is missing the parameter for the class instance, so:

```py
class ServerErrorView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "client_interface/errors/500.html")
```

Best django practice would be to define the GET method as `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Unfortunately bot `get(self, request)` and `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` still throw the same error: `The custom handler500 view 'client_interface.views.errors.server_error_view.ServerErrorView' does not take the correct number of arguments (request).`