# Django Integrity error at .... null value in column

Tags: python, django

New to Django, getting a violates not-null constraint, that's preventing it from posting to my DB(elephantSQL), I can't seem to get around this issue even when passing the post.id in urls, in the 'buttons' and the view...

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully someone can point me to the right direction. I have very little experience with this and I'm trying to learn.

I have tried a few good things, though I can't seem to get it to post. HELP!!!!

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, reverse
from django.views import generic, View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import CommentForm, ReviewForm
from .models import Post, Comment, ReviewRating


def index(request):
    """ a view to retuern the index page """

    return render(request, 'market/index.html')


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'market/market.html'
    paginate_by = 6


class PostDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by("-created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        return render(request, "market/post_detail.html",
                      {
                        "post": post,
                        "comments": comments,
                        "commented": False,
                        "liked": liked,
                        "comment_form": CommentForm()
                      },
                      )

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by("created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.comment = post
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully added a Comment')
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
            messages.info(request,
                          'Oops! somthing wasnt right there,\
                            make sure you are logged and try again!')

        return render(
            request,
            "market/post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": True,
                "liked": liked,
                "comment_form": comment_form
            },
        )


class PostLike(View):

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            messages.info(request,
                          'Sorry you didnt love this as much as we do!')
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            messages.success(request, 'We loved this too!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug]))


def createReview(request):
    form = ReviewForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post.objects.get()
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect('market_posts/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'market/review_form.html', context)


def editReview(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ReviewForm(instance=post)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'market/review_form.html', context)


def deleteReview(request, pk):
    post = post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        order.delete()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'item': order}
    return render(request, 'market/delete.html', context)
```

Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="market_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Reaction {self.body} Posted by {self.name}'


class ReviewRating(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="rating_user")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.slug
```

Urls

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('market_posts/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='market_posts'),
    path('market/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(),
         name='post_detail'),

    path('like/<slug:slug>', views.PostLike.as_view(), name="post_like"),

    path('create_review/', views.createReview, name="create_review"),
    path('edit_review/', views.editReview, name="edit_review"),
    path('delete_review/', views.deleteReview, name="delete_review")
]
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Comment, ReviewRating
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)


class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRating
        fields = ['rating', 'subject', 'review' ]
```

review_forms

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2 my-auto">
        <h1 class="display-1 "><strong>Market Place</strong></h1>
        <h2 class="text-uppercase py-3 ">Food Glorious Food</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-9">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <form action="{% url 'create_review' %}" method="POST" class="d-inline-block">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="my-4">Rating between 1-5</p>
            {{ form.rating }}
            <br>
            <p class="my-4">Subject:</p>
            {{ form.subject }}
            <br>
            <p class="my-4">Review:</p>
            {{ form.review }}
            <input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-signup" name="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2npQl.png)

Comment: Add `ReviewForm` in your question

Comment: No joy there, I think the problem is passing the post_id but im not sure how to do that correctly.

Comment: post = Post.objects.get(post_id=post_id)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `post_id` in the ReviewForm's field list and also add hidden input type in html form with value of your post instance id like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
```

*forms.py*:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRating
        fields = ['post_id', 'rating', 'subject', 'review' ]
```

Comment: Sadly not, I think its to do with the post id, and the view and url??

Comment: like this?

def createReview(request, post_id):
    form = ReviewForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST, post_id=post_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('market_posts/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'market/review_form.html', context)

Comment: I haved edited the answer check

Comment: OK, thanks, thats not crashing or showing an error message but it hasn't updated the DB.

Comment: Can you try the OR part only. Just add 'post' field in form field list and this `{{ form.post.as_hidden }}` in your form html remove save method and input type for now.

Comment: <form action="{% url 'create_review' %}" method="POST" class="d-inline-block">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="my-4">Rating between 1-5</p>
            {{ form.rating }}
            <br>
            <p class="my-4">Subject:</p>
            {{ form.subject }}
            <br>
            <p class="my-4">Review:</p>
            {{ form.review }}
            {{ form.post.as_hidden }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-signup" name="Submit">
        </form>

Comment: Like that? its not updating the DB, my other views are workign so its not the DB connection. Django is confusing ;(

Comment: Did you removed save method and input type ?

Comment: I have removed the save method from the forms.py. I removed the input in the html that you had suggested above tho I have a submit button still as an input type.

Comment: @Jonny You have the post id in form html right ? if yes then just add `<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">` in your form html and then add `post_id` in `ReviewForm` field list that is it. Try that

Comment: I have it in the form action. I have updated the original question with the full views.py file. if that makes sense?

Comment: Do you have access to post instance in your `review_form.html` ?

Comment: <form action="{% url 'create_review' %}" method="POST" class="d-inline-block">

Comment: {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="my-4">Rating between 1-5</p>
            {{ form.rating }}
            <br>
            <p class="my-4">Subject:</p>
            {{ form.subject }}
            <br>
            <p class="my-4">Review:</p>
            {{ form.review }}

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-signup" name="Submit">
        </form>

Comment: How would you get the value of `{{post.id}}` ? Is this whole html form included in post detail template or any other template ? On the UI you would be showing Post detail and then below it the review there at last would be review form html ? You can check in inspect if you get any value in the hidden input type

Comment: the post_detail.html template (when you click the 'create review' button) goes through to the review_form.html which as the form currently as above. 
do i need a for loop to loop through and get post id? 
{% for p in post %}
    {{ p.post.id }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Why do you have to loop ? In the post detail you have only one post instance right ? And you want to add review for it using review_form.html right ?

Comment: There are multiple posts that different reviews are on, So I was assuming I had to loop to get the right post that the review is attached to? 
but there is only one post in the post detail page that it could be attached to. So no loop. Your correct there

Comment: So your review form html should be inside of post detail html actually below it.

Comment: I moved the form to a separate page because it was triggering the comments form that is on the post_detail.html as well as not displaying the form inputs areas.

Comment: Which form ? And to where ? What happened with review_form ?

Answer (score 0):

In your model you defined post as not nullable

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you are not adding it to your form:

```py
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRating
        fields = ['rating', 'subject', 'review' ]
```

Result is you try to create ReviewRating without data populated for not nullable field.

Solution:
1)Change post field to be nullable

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, nullable=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

2. Change fields in ReviewForm

   fields = ['rating', 'subject', 'review', 'post']

Also reading your comment is what you probably want to do is
Change in forms:

```py
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRating
        fields = ['rating', 'subject', 'review', 'post']
        widgets = {'post': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

Then modify views

```py
def createReview(request):
    # as you said you wanted to pass it through url so here is my proposal with query param post_id
    post_data = request.GET.get('post_id')
    if not post_data:
        raise ValidationError("If there is no query param we raise error as we can't make model without post")
    form = ReviewForm(initial={'post': post_data})
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('market_posts/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'market/review_form.html', context)
```

There are different approach to accomplish that, this is only one of possibilites

Comment: Cant i automatically poss it that in the views from my Post model? as this is a review on a specific post?

Comment: @Jonny of course you can, django is quite flexible, but you don't do that so you have error. And you probably have to inject it to form data before validating form

Comment: so if i pass it like this, 
def createReview(request, post_id):
How do i access it to so that it will post this to my DB with the rest of the info from the form. I know this is prob really basic but its my 1st Django project

Comment: TypeError at /create_review/1
'QueryDict' object is not callable

thats giving me the following error

Comment: ```form = ReviewForm(initial={'post': request.GET.get('post_id')})``` and query params are used with param name  */create_review/?post_id=1*

Answer (score 0):

The form does not have the post object, so you are sending in nothing in the form with `{{ form.post.as_hidden }}`.  You can send the specific `Post` in the context, then you can send it through the HTML, or you can set the intial value of the form like this, `form = ReviewForm(initial={'post': post})`.  Or, as I wrote in the answer below, get it in the view.
Either way you have to get the `Post` instance the form is trying to update.

```py
def createReview(request):
    form = ReviewForm()
    # get the Post object
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post.objects.get(.....)
            # commit=False so the form is not saved to database yet,
            # but it's in the memory so you can update it
            form.save(commit=False)
            # update the form
            form.post = post
            # finally save the form
            form.save()
            return redirect('market_posts/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'market/review_form.html', context)
```

Comment: I would put Post get query inside the if condition.

Comment: Thanks, @Ahtisham  Yes, that makes more sense.

Comment: you don't actually need to get the Post object from db you can simply put `form.post_id = post_id`

Comment: def createReview(request):
    form = ReviewForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post.objects.get(post_id=post_id)
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect('market_posts/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'market/review_form.html', context)

Comment: I have updated to as above, with the 
post = Post.objects.get(post_id=post_id)
like so is that what you mean? This is not posting to DB. Though it looks much more like something I recognise

Comment: also tried 
post = Post.objects.get(instance=form) 

which returned

Cannot resolve keyword 'instance' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, comments, content, created_on, excerpt, featured_image, id, likes, reviewrating, slug, status, title, updated_on


sorry again i know this is like feeding a baby!

Comment: You use `post_id=post_id` but where is this view getting `post_id` from?  Unless you're hiding part of the view, this should give you an error.  That's why I left it as `post = Post.objects.get(.....)`

Comment: sorry I thought i was to fill it in. lol
when i leave it blank 
   post = Post.objects.get() 
it returns the following 

MultipleObjectsReturned at /create_review/
get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  You're not telling Django *which* `Post` instance you want the `ReviewRating` associated with anywhere in your code.  The `createReview` view doesn't know what `post_id` is, you're not sending it in the template, as a parameter.

Comment: @raphael I have updated the original question with the full views.py file. The 1st class is the Post method, and the reviews section I'm trying to carry out a review with CRUD functionality on a particular post. 
I probably am missing the point, I appreciate all the help, this is my 1st Django project

Comment: You are mixing function based views and class based views.  It's ok if you know what you're doing, but I'm rusty with class based views.  However, the problem is the same.  Look at your `editReview` @Jonny and compare it to the `createView`.  In the `editView` you are getting the `Post` instance first.  The `createReview` function has no idea which `Post` the `ReviewRating` is associated with.

Comment: If you *are* sending the post instance in your HTML, then @Ahtisham answer should work.

Comment: Is it  bad practice to mix class based and function based?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621346/10951070